# adding New Relic to laravel forge HHVM or none

Tags: laravel, newrelic, lumen, hhvm

I have been trying to add newrelic support for the better half of the day now. (isn't this supposed to be easy?) Thinking I might be running into issues because of forge? I know Forge used to have the ability to plug in a key and your off to the races. I no longer see that option?... Did they remove support of NewRelic?

I keep getting the following issue when even trying to install manually using New Relics instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install newrelic-php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package newrelic-php5
```

Using Laravel Forge, Lumen, Amazon AWS, HHVM and None (2 instances running)

Thanks

Citti

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could make the installation work, unfortunately New Relic doesn't support HHVM nor they are planning to.